# Transcribing syslog and preserving the line breaks

Tags: support, formatting

I'm trying to copy a segment of my `syslog` to a question here.

The problem is that all the linefeeds are lost when I do the copy, so the transcription is very difficult to read.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please see here: [formatting tools](https://meta.askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 7):

You need to apply **code formatting** to the copy/pasted code.

This can be done by first copy/pasting in the content from the logs, then *selecting* the copied-in text completely, and hitting the button that looks like `{ }` to apply code formatting.

This will properly make your log data look like it came from the terminal, just like I did to your question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034980/why-is-the-canary-starving) via an edit to apply the code formatting.

This way by applying code formatting, you prevent this:

```
foo
bar
baz
CAKE
IS
A
LIE
```

... from becoming this:

foo
bar
baz
CAKE
IS
A
LIE

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply *preformatted text* **formatting** by using the `{}` icon above the editor window here, after having selected your syslog text.

For more details, please see the relevant help center page here: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting